# jQuery check if element has a specific style property (display)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to have a if/else statement inside a function. How do you check if an element (e.g. #cadrage) has a display style property? This is what I have found around the net and yet, it is not working..

```
if( $('#cadrage').attr('style').display == 'block' ) {
      // do something
} else {
      // do something
}
```

Comment: Note it's preferable to use the `style` property over the attribute one: `$('#cadrage').prop('style')`.

Answer (score 27):

The jQuery .css() function seems to be what you want.

```
if( $('#cadrage').css('display') == 'block' ) {
   console.log('It equal block');
} else {
   console.log('It did not equal block');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SamMonk/FtP6W/

Answer (score 9):

Your code doesn't work because `style` property only contains inline styles, not those coming from a stylesheet.

To get the computed style, you can use [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css1) method:

```
$('#cadrage').css('display') == 'block'
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you ask for, but perhaps what you are looking for...

You can use the `:visible` pseudo selector to check if the element is visible:

```
if( $('#cadrage').is(':visible')) {
      // do something
} else {
      // do something
}
```

Note that this doesn't actually check the `display` style, but rather if the element has a size so that it could be seen in the page.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if( $('#cadrage').css('display')== 'block' ) {
      // do something
} else {
      // do something
}
```

Comment: I think you have an additional `display` in `.css('display').display`

Answer (score 2):

You can get your element display property with the following code snippet

```
$('#cadrage').css('display');
```

Note that the `css` method can return any css property of your element so it is very handy.
Therefore your statement code will be:

```
if( $('#cadrage').css('display').display == 'block' ) {
      // do something
} else {
      // do something
}
```