# How to check if a div have a certain css property with a specific value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want ask if is possible check in `JQuery`, if a div have a certain property and if have a specific value. So take this example:

```
<div id="foo" style="width: 100%" />
```

I need to check if the div `foo` have the css property `width` and if this have a value of `100%`.

What I can do for achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591327/jquery-check-if-element-has-a-specific-style-property-display

Comment: @Richard unfortunately that question gives the computed styles when it comes to width - the question would be more a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126670/return-css-height-with-jquery-not-computed-but-declared

Comment: Anyway - you need to use the native js object and use the style : `$('#foo').get(0).style.width`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to select the element based on inline style attribute then you can use attribute contains selector but this may fail when there is extra space within the defenition.

```js
if (('#foo[style*="width: 100%"]').length)
  alert('true')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo" style="width: 100%" />
```

---

To resolve the issue with space you can use regex with [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method on style attribute.

```js
if (/\bwidth\s?:\s?100%/.test($('#foo').attr('style')))
  alert('true')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo" style="width: 100%" />
```

Comment: uhm, nope, I'm trying to check if the div `foo` have the `width` property and also if this have a value of `100%`, actually I tried like so: `if($('#foo').css('width') == '100') { alert(true); }` but not seems to be working

Comment: @AgainMe : updated

Comment: Ok so is enough a `length` for check this, never though to this. Thanks