# How to check element have transform properties with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to check when `custom-class` has style `transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3d(1, 1, 1);`

I have check stackoverflow [demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591327/jquery-check-if-element-has-a-specific-style-property-display/24591371) but its only work for `opacity` in my case but i can't check for `transform` css properties.

```js
if( $('.custom-class').css('opacity') == '1' ) {
   console.log('It opacity checked');
} else {
   console.log('It opacity unchecked ');
}

if( $('.custom-class').css('transform') == 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3d(1, 1, 1)' ) {
   console.log('It transform checked');
} else {
   console.log('It transform unchecked');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="custom-class" style="opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3d(1, 1, 1);"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery [`.css`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) method (as a getter, not a setter) uses the [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) internally

From MDN (emphasis mine):

> Get the **value of a computed style property** for the first element in
> the set of matched elements or set one or more CSS properties for
> every matched element.

So `$('.custom-class').css('transform')` is actually `self.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.custom-class')).getPropertyValue('transform')`

For performance reasons this is a `matrix` value. Your transformation is the non translating identity transformation (don't scale, skew or rotate and don't translate), which is the matrix value of `matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)`

If you want to have the *real* value of the style, you need to use VanillaJS `document.querySelector('.custom-class').style.transform` instead

Or just compare with the matrix value

```
// ...
if( $('.custom-class').css('transform') == 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)' ) {
// ...
```

```js
if( $('.custom-class').css('opacity') == '1' ) {
   console.log('It opacity checked');
} else {
   console.log('It opacity unchecked ');
}
console.log(self.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.custom-class')).getPropertyValue('transform'))
console.log($('.custom-class').css('transform'))
console.log(document.querySelector('.custom-class').style.transform)

if( $('.custom-class').css('transform') == 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)' ) {
   console.log('It transform checked');
} else {
   console.log('It transform unchecked');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="custom-class" style="opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3d(1, 1, 1);"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks but i want check for translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) property.

Comment: @JigneshPanchal Only `rotateX()`, `rotateY()`, `translateZ()` and `scaleZ()` trigger a 3d transformation, if they don't have default values of 0 (or 1 in case of scale).

Comment: @JigneshPanchal See this demonstration: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/LYNWgvX

Comment: @JigneshPanchal So you want to only check for the element not being translated? Your OP doesn't reflect that very much